# Can we select a specific row of records from a confluent kafka topic?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, ksqldb

In my local Confluent Platform, I have 1 topic call "FOO_02", I have manually insert some records to it, thus, I can print it from beginning base on the following command:

```
print 'FOO_02' from beginning;
```

[image]

Can I do something like, I only want to pull the record where COL1 = 1? Something like we can execute a select statement with where condition to pull the data from normal database like `db2`.

I have try the following command but I believe it will only get the new data, because I am getting empty record for this command:

```
ksql> select * from FOO_02 WHERE COL1=1 EMIT CHANGES;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm presuming that you've already done

```sql
CREATE STREAM FOO_02 WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='FOO_02', FORMAT='AVRO');
```

because otherwise your `SELECT` would have failed.

So since the `PRINT` shows successfully that there is data in the *topic* you can query the stream using the predicate you want. The only thing you need to do is tell ksqlDB to process *all* the data in the topic and not just the new records (which is what `from beginning` does in the `PRINT` statement). To do this, run:

```sql
SET 'auto.offset.reset' = 'earliest';
```

and *then* run the `SELECT`.

---

*Edit*

> Can we select the only latest records? For example, I have multiple data being push to topic for COL1=0, but I only want to grab the latest one because its the newest data and it is the only correct one. something like where rowtime = max?

What you're describing is a `TABLE`: the latest value for a given key.

```sql
CREATE TABLE FOO AS
  SELECT COL1, 
         LATEST_BY_OFFSET(COL2) AS COL2
    FROM FOO_02
   WHERE COL1=0
   GROUP BY COL1;
```

The resulting table will have a single entry for `COL1`, with the latest value of `COL2` as new messages are received.

> Any way to bring the old data in the Stream into the table as well?

To process existing data too set the offset back to earliest before running the `CREATE` statement

```sql
SET 'auto.offset.reset' = 'earliest';

CREATE TABLE FOO AS
[…]
```

Comment: Can we select the only latest records? For example, I have multiple data being push to topic for COL1=0, but I only want to grab the latest one because its the newest data and it is the only correct one. something like where rowtime = max?

Comment: hi @Robin, it will only store the new message in the new created table? Any way to bring the old data in the Stream into the table as well?